# print X items from list at scheduled time intervals

Tags: python, arrays, scheduled-tasks

I have a json array with some data (name,address), I'd like to print one name every five minutes: so far I've got this:

```
def get_data(i):
    f = open('data.json' , 'r')
    infos = json.load(f)
    name = infos['people'][i]['name']
    print(name)
    i+=1
schedule.every(5).minutes.do(get_data, i=0)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

but it obviously doesn't work because I'm setting i to zero every time that get_data gets called, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe wrap this function in a class? Or use a global variable if your code is simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap this function in a class like so:

```py
import schedule
import json
import time


class Run:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 0

    def get_data(self):
        with open('data.json') as f:
            infos = json.load(f)

        try:
            name = infos['people'][self.i]['name']
            print(name)
        except IndexError:
            print('No name for index:', self.i)
        else:
            self.i += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run = Run()
    schedule.every(5).minutes.do(Run.get_data, run)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```